# Symfony Forms: Persisiting object with constructor to Databese

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to persist an object of an entity to the database using symfony forms. The entity has an constructor therefore I am giving the object dummy data but I am not able to change this data with the forms. Does anyone have a solution how to create an object that requires a constructor?

```
 public function new(Request $request)
    {

        $player = new Player("Dummy",0);




        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($player)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('points', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Player'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $data = $form->getData();
        $name = $data->getName();
       error_log($name);




        $this->PlayerRepository->store($player);



        return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

$name has always the value "Dummy" no matter what I type in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You save `$player` here:

```
$this->PlayerRepository->store($player);
```

But your actual player data from form is in `$data`, and this `$data` should be stored:

```
$this->PlayerRepository->store($data);
```

Comment: Actually, due to the way Symfony forms work, $player will have any updated information in it.  The use of getData is unnecessary in this case.  The original poster really just needs to follow the examples in the docs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
But the values data contains are always "Dummy" and 0.
So there seems to be a mistake that the data entered in the form is not actually submitted. Therefore form->getData does not give me the data I need to have.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seems that I found the mistake.

I did not define the POST Route for the same controller building the view.

sorry for that :)